# How to implement MVVM properly in android in order to unit test the app

Tags: android, mvvm

I saw many tuts regarding android data binding, but still confused how to exactly use it, more i read these tuts more i get confused because every one have their own implementation of it
Some say you should not use android things like context inside view model, it should have only business login 
But some freely use same inside view model
So i want to know should i use context inside my view model, if no then how to perform those task that requires context

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently developing an app using Model-View-ViewModel pattern (with [Android Data Binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html)). The most important reason you're not suppose to use Android framework components in your business logic is testability. When I need it, I inject Context to ViewModel and swap it for the mocked Context in unit tests.

Also, make sure you are not [leaking Context](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.es/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html) in your particular case.

Comment: But many people say we should not have direct access of view in viewmodel

Comment: Well in all implementations of MVP and MVVM I've seen there is at least some access to the View from Presenter or ViewModel :) In this case if you need access to Context you don't pass the one from your view, but the "global" one by calling https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getApplicationContext().